# Hiding Navigation bar without decreasing the size of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

In my app, i need Navigation controllers but i don't need their navigation bar (i have my own custom bars), so When i try to hide the Navigation bar in the launch of the app with so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}
```

The Bar is hidden, but it take its size too, s the size of the view is decreased.
Is there any way to hide the navigation bar without effecting the size of the screen?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No.

What you could do, however, is add your custom bar to the correct position on the application's window `[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow addSubview:myCustomNavBar]`, and have that simply display over the navigation bar, if that will work for you.